# Update few Properties of Model after Inserting in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model, insert-update

In my `ASP.NET Web forms` app, I have a `Model` whose `ID` is of type IDENTITY of type int. In my `Insert`, after saving the item, I create a directory of that itemId & want to save images in it & update the image Paths of the same in the Item. On updating the item properties & trying to save, it gives me an error:-

```
The property 'ChannelId' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
```

My Insert Methods :

```
    public void InsertItem()
    {
        Channel item = null;
        item = new Channel();

        TryUpdateModel(item);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            // Save changes
            // After this line only I can get the ID created by DB
            _db.SaveChanges();
            _db.Channels.Add(item);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("###  EF ID OF Newly Created CHANNEL = " + item.ChannelId);

            // Create Folder for the Channel based on its ID
            string pathToCreate = "~/CRMImages/Channels/" + item.ChannelId;
            string myFileName = "";
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate)))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
                var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
                var userName = user.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
                System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity sec = di.GetAccessControl();
                sec.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(userName,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Modify,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                di.SetAccessControl(sec);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CHannel FOLDER CREATED PATH : " + di.FullName);
                myFileName = pathToCreate + "/pancardImg.png";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PATH To Save PAN File & NAME : " + myFileName);

                // PAN CARD IMAGE
                FileUpload panInsertUpload = InsertChannelId.FindControl("panInsertUpload") as FileUpload;
                if (panInsertUpload != null)
                {
                    if (panInsertUpload.HasFile)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EDIT UNIT PLAN FILE NAME =" + panInsertUpload.FileName);
                        myFileName = pathToCreate + "/pancardImg.png";
                        panInsertUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(myFileName));
                        item.PanImageURL = myFileName;
                    }
                }

                TryUpdateModel(item);
                // HERE I GET THE ERROR. HOW TO UPDATE THAT ITEM IN DB
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            Response.Redirect("Default");
        }
    }
```

The directory is being created, file is being saved all proper, just how do I update the properties to the DB. After creating the dir & saving the file only I can get the file path to be saved.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What are using the TryUpdateModel for?

Comment: Yes Praveen, I tried that & it worked. Can you add your answer so I can mark it as Answer. Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you need not be using TryUpdateModel after setting the item.PanImageUrl. Remove the section which has the TryUpdateModel here.

```
//TryUpdateModel(item);
// HERE I GET THE ERROR. HOW TO UPDATE THAT ITEM IN DB
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Also I noticed that you are calling SaveChanges before adding it to the collection. I think it should be the other way around.

```
// Save changes
// After this line only I can get the ID created by DB
_db.Channels.Add(item);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Praveen, so for every Update of this type, their is no need for TryUpdateModel(). How do I update the edited item in DbSet of the Context ? In other Model, the updates are not reflected in DbSet while returning to Default.aspx unless I manually click F5 to refresh the page. In that Model, I get this problem in Edit.aspx and I redirect to Default the same way, But this happens only when I edit the images thru FileUpload, not otherwise.

Comment: The second TryUpdateModel needs to be removed. You use this method to initially load the Entity from the Controller context. You have done this before adding to the DB. After that, you can update the properties and called SaveChanges directly

Comment: Can you please try to help me with this query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350069/button-click-in-a-tablecell-never-fires-and-table-disappears?noredirect=1#comment46887378_29350069       I am unable to fire Button click added in a table dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

replace TryUpdateModel by TryValidateModel

```
public void InsertItem()
    {
        Channel item = null;
        item = new Channel();

        TryUpdateModel(item);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            // Save changes
            _db.Channels.Add(item);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("###  EF ID OF Newly Created CHANNEL = " + item.ChannelId);

            // Create Folder for the Channel based on its ID
            string pathToCreate = "~/CRMImages/Channels/" + item.ChannelId;
            string myFileName = "";
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate)))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
                var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
                var userName = user.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
                System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity sec = di.GetAccessControl();
                sec.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(userName,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Modify,
                    System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                di.SetAccessControl(sec);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CHannel FOLDER CREATED PATH : " + di.FullName);
                myFileName = pathToCreate + "/pancardImg.png";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PATH To Save PAN File & NAME : " + myFileName);

                // PAN CARD IMAGE
                FileUpload panInsertUpload = InsertChannelId.FindControl("panInsertUpload") as FileUpload;
                if (panInsertUpload != null)
                {
                    if (panInsertUpload.HasFile)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EDIT UNIT PLAN FILE NAME =" + panInsertUpload.FileName);
                        myFileName = pathToCreate + "/pancardImg.png";
                        panInsertUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(myFileName));
                        item.PanImageURL = myFileName;
                    }
                }

                TryValidateModel(item);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            Response.Redirect("Default");
        }
    }
```

One more working code sample,

```
[HttpPost]

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        int empId = employee.EmployeeID;
        employee.LName = "abc";
        TryValidateModel(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Smita. But in WebForms I only have TryUpdateModel & not TryValidateModel.